# load dynamic data in html modal in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-views

I have single html page with dynamic images from database in **Django**.
I also have a modal in the same page set to invisible and opens when image is clicked.

My intension is when I click on any image it should **open a html model with the clicked image** and its description text from db.

How do I **display data of the current clicked image and its description**.
I have tried to pass `{{profile.image.url}}` but this gives one information on click to all images.

I didn't have to give sample code on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by passing the id of the object you want to retrieve using AJAX request.

Let's suppose, this is your HTML table

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {% for incident in page_obj %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ incident.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ incident.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ incident.created }}</td>
        <td>
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">{{ incident.get_status_display }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" onclick="populateForm('{{ incident.id }}')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#incidentModal">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Use this type of function according to your model and fields

```
 function populateForm(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'incidents:update' 1 %}".replace("1", id),
      type: "GET",
      success(response) {
        let incident = JSON.parse(response)[0].fields;
        $("#id_title").val(incident.title);
        $("#id_description").val(incident.description);
        $("#id_responder").val(incident.responder);
        $("#id_status").val(incident.status);
        $("#id_functional_impact").val(incident.functional_impact);
        $("#id_information_impact").val(incident.information_impact);
        $("#id_recovery_impact").val(incident.recovery_impact);
      },
    });
  }
```

views.py

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse, Http404
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from incidents.models import Incident
from incidents.forms import IncidentForm


class IncidentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = IncidentForm
    model = Incident

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('incidents:list')

    def get(self, request, pk):
        if request.is_ajax():
            incident = get_object_or_404(Incident, pk=pk)
            response = serializers.serialize("json", [incident])
            return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
        raise Http404('Page not found')
```

Comment: Hi! Good answer! I´m having this same question. I have a grid of users and a delete button for each user . I want when this button is pressed to open a modal saying "Are you sure you want to delete user "UserName"? so when confirming i want to delete user. I cannot achieve to "store" selected user in grid" and pass it to modal withous using ajax? Thanks    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028775/foundation-modal-instantly-closing

Comment: Hey, sorry for the very late response. You can attach a javascript function to your button's onclick method and pass the user id in it as an argument. In the function, you can set the delete form's action with user's id. So, whenever user clicks on Delete button, that function will change form's action and a modal will appear, and on confirming it will submit the form which will eventually results in user being deleted. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options on how to achieve this:

1. render modals for all images with django and open them when user clicks one of the images.
2. create 1 modal and write some javascript to fetch information about the clicked image in the background. Note, that you'll also need to create an endpoint in  Django that will accept image ID and return image information.